# Dictionary Attack on SHA-1 hashes

Tags: cryptography, python

The following is a Python code to crack SHA1 hash. This code does not seem to work.

```
import hashlib
# plug in the hash that needs to be cracked
hash_to_crack = "7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b"
# open the dictionary file
dict_file = "dictionary.txt"

def main():
    with open(dict_file) as fileobj:
        for line in fileobj:
            line = line.strip()
            if hashlib.sha1(line).hexdigest() == hash_to_crack:
                print ("Successfully cracked the hash %s: It is %s") % (hash_to_crack, line);
            return ""
print ("Failed to crack the file.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output I got :-

```
 RESTART: C:/Users/kiran/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Codes/datest1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kiran/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Codes/datest1.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/kiran/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Codes/datest1.py", line 8, in main
    with open(dict_file) as fileobj:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dictionary.txt'
```

P.S I am beginner when it comes to coding.  Please help me fix this code.

Comment: Welcome! This question does not belong here as it is a general programming question, so I've voted to move it to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the place for this question. Since it's a Info Security thing, but good that you're trying.

The FileNotFound error is basically saying that there is no File to be found. Python is looking for the dictionary.txt file in the `C:/Users/kiran/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Codes/` directory, and couldn't find it.

On a 'not so infosec' note, you should have a return statement within the if block, but not in the for block. That way, the program stops after a hash is found. The way your code is written, the program will terminate after the first iteration of the for loop.

```
def main():
    with open(dict_file) as fileobj:
        for line in fileobj:
            line = line.strip()
            if hashlib.sha1(line).hexdigest() == hash_to_crack:
                print ("Successfully cracked the hash %s: It is %s") % (hash_to_crack, line);
                return  # returns after a hash is foud

    print ("Failed to crack the file.")
    return  # returns if all hashes in dictionary.txt is exhausted
```

Comment: It's looking for dictionary.txt in whatever the user's working directory was when they ran the script, which might be different from the directory the script's in.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there's file with name `dictionary.txt` in same directory.

Advice: use online services to decrypt hashes :)